# How to create a batch file to run jar file?

Tags: java, jar

I run a jar file through batch. i used the command

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

After jar file executed prompt window closed. i wrote a pause command to hold window wait for any key to prees. but my requirement is prompt should allow me to type some commands of my choice. until i type exit command prompt should open .

Comment: should your command be interpreted by your java program? In that case it's not the batch file that you need to edit. Otherwise just start an shell (bash or cmd in windows) and run the java program in that

Comment: I don't think you can do that. When the OS launches a shell to run a batch job, it terminates that shell when the job ends. There's no way to get at the command prompt once the batch ends, unless you invoked the batch from a command prompt to begin with.